# Ensure methods called are within Spring @Transactional boundary

Tags: java, database, spring

I'm using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and am calling methods that I only want to be able to be called from a method annotated with `@Transactional`.

For reasons I won't pollute this question with, the methods I want to call as part of the transaction should never be called out with the transaction boundary and I want to enforce this.

Is there an annotation or similar I can use to ensure these methods are only able to be successfully called from a method annotated with `@Transactional`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simplest case you can use `Propagation.MANDATORY` (i.e. `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)`) transactional propagation instead of default `Propagation.REQUIRED`.

If you use programmatic transactions then you check `TransactionStatus` getters - even if your propagation is `REQUIRED` you can verify that  `TransactionStatus.isNewTransaction()` returns false.